# SQL Rollback Transaction without begin transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have updated my SQL table without  writting

```
begin transaction
```

Is there any system to retrieve back my data

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Is restoring backups an option? Is is a single case where you need to recover data or should it be a part of your application doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Only to restore to the last know stable backup.

Comment: Well the answer is you cannot use a `ROLLBACK`. Depending on the complexity of the operation/`UPDATE` you did you might be able to perform the reverse operation. Howevr, it is likely that is not possible. I which case the only way to restore the data is to perform a restore operation from a database backup. I am sure you'll have a back up of your database ready and waiting right?

Answer (score 0):

Rollback will only work if you started an explicit transaction before the delete, and that transaction has not yet committed.

To get the data back, get your latest database backup, restore it as a new DB (not over the current database), restore log backups up to the point just before the delete, then copy the data over to the main database.